# How to remove particular columns in SSIS package while doing transformation?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

I want to remove a few columns from my flat file as I want to load in SQL server Data Warehouse using SSIS, How I can achieve this transformation using SSIS, see attachment for description. For e.g. I don't want `%Salary` and `Address` in my transformation.

[image]

Comment: There is no need in any transformation. Just don't select/map not needed columns on the Destination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the below steps:

1. Create Data Flow Task
2. Define Flat File Source and create new connection manager and point to source file.
3. Create empty flat file with the headers you want. Define Flat File Destination and point to Flat file empty destination, by following the subsequent steps.
4. Right click Flat file destination, click Edit. It will be throwing a popup as given below. Click `Yes`.

[image]

4. Define new connection manager pointing to destination file.

[image]

4. Now, point to your empty destination file. If you go to columns tab, only specific columns will be present.
   [image: Browse to empty destination file]
5. Now, connect the Flat file source to Flat file destination. Now, only specific columns will be mapped as given below:

[image: Mapping specific columns]

6.Now, you run the package, only specific columns will be loaded.

[image: running specific columns load package]

**UPDATE**: Sorry. I misunderstood destination as Flat File Destination. If you are having SQL Server Data Warehouse as the destination, you need to follow below steps.

1. you can create Table in destination with specific columns.
2. Connect Flat file source to  OLEDB Destination, as given below:

[image: SQL Server Destination]

3. Mapping should be done only for specific columns. You dont need specific transformations in the middle.

[image: OLEDB mapping]

Comment: It seems that the OP needs to load a flat file into a database table.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, yes. Sorry. I misunderstood the question. I thought he wanted to only load specific columns to flat file destination.  I will update my answer to make it suitable to the OP question.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, I have updated my answer. I have kept the original Flat file destination also, if somebody finds them as useful.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the provided approach will work fine, why you should load all useless columns into your data pipeline to ignore them at the end. **You can simply uncheck them from the *Flat File Source* editor.**

[image]